# How to connect J-link OB to an RF transceiver module?

Tags: swd, interconnect, cortex-m0, j-link

I'm looking to program the RFM380F32 RF transceiver module which includes an ARM Cortex-M0+ processor: http://www.hoperf.cn/modules/soc/RFM380F32.html

The documentation suggests programming in Keil and using J-Link OB for debugging and flash download. The module is brand new and I was unable to find an evaluation board.

I'm wondering if matching the VCC, GND, SWDIO, SWDCLK pins on the J-Link to the same pins on the module will suffice or if I need to add resistors or other components for the connections to SWDIO and SWDCLK.

Comment: What does the data sheet suggest?

Comment: The datasheet only states: "For debugging, users can use J-Link debugger, an easily reached debugging tool in the market. J-Link V8 or J-Link OB is recommended.... The Cortex M0+ core integrated in the CMT2380F32 supports SWD debugging interface, which requires only 4 wires (VCC, GND, SWDIO, SWDCLK) for debugging"

Comment: `I'm wondering if matching the VCC, GND, SWDIO, SWDCLK pins on the J-Link to the same pins on the module will suffice` Yup, that's sufficient. This applies to other chips having integrated M4 core (e.g. Nordic nRF528xx) as well.

Comment: You probably want a hardware reset too unless it's multiplexed, this will be especially key once your code sleeps the processor.  Also, see the jlink manual

Comment: Thank you! Found this J-link manual: cypress.com/file/291476/download (page 176), it seems that I'll only need one 100k pull-up resistor on my board and a 0.1" header for the connections